# Rails Rspec & FactoryGirl testing Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I have to model's where I accept Nested Attributes. I would like to build a test to make sure the nested attribute cant be blank etc. I really don't understand how I can make the test.

My two simple models:

```
# SeoMapping Model
class SeoMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mappingtable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :seo_url
  validates :seo_url, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true   
end

# Page Model
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :seo_mappings, :as => :mappingtable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seo_mappings 
  attr_accessible :content, :h1, :meta_description, :title, :seo_mappings_attributes
  .........
end
```

Here are my factories for Page and Seo:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :page do |f|
    seo_mapping
    f.title { Faker::Name.name }
    f.h1 { Faker::Lorem.words(5) }
    f.meta_description { Faker::Lorem.words(10) }
    f.content { Faker::Lorem.words(30) }
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :seo_mapping do |f|
    f.seo_url { Faker::Internet.domain_word }
  end
end
```

And my tests:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Page do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    expect(create(:page)).to be_valid
  end

  # Cant get this spec to work?
  it "it is invalid without a seo_url" do
    page = build(:page)
    seo_mapping = build(:seo_mapping, seo_url: nil)
    page.seo_mapping.should_not be_valid
    # expect(build(:page, :seo_mapping_attributes[:seo_url] => nil)).to_not be_valid
  end

  it "is invalid without a title" do
    expect(build(:page, title: nil)).to_not be_valid
  end
  ...............
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually for this sort of thing I use a gem called [shoulda_matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers). It lets you simply assert that your model validates presence of specific attributes.

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:seo_url) }
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:seo_url) }
```

If you don't want to use the gem, try something like this:

```
seo_mapping = build(:seo_mapping, seo_url: nil)
page = build(:page, seo_mapping: seo_mapping)
page.should_not be_valid
```

Comment: TY I like the Shoulda gem. But if I try it { should validate_presence_of(:seo_url) } I get error "undefined method `seo_url='" It seems to me it does not like associations validation on one model ?